# Update object in nested array in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, nested-forms, angular-reactive-forms

I have a nested form:

```
this.contactForm = this.fb.group({
  name: ['', Validators.required],
  description: '',
  comment: '',
  phone: '',,
  addresses: this.fb.array([])
});

get addresses() {
 return this.contactForm.get('addresses') as FormArray;
}
```

I am opening a modal via ng-bootstrap. So I am able to populate the modal with the correct data.
I am also able to delete it properly.
But once I open the modal and edit the values I am saving a new object and not updating it.

I use a service to communicate between components:

Parent:

```
this.companyService.addressCompanySubject.subscribe(
  data => {
    const address = this.fb.group({
      addressType: data.addressType,
      street: data.street,
      zip: data.zip,
      city: data.city,
      country: data.country
    });
    this.addresses.push(address);
  }
);
```

Child:

```
sendAddress() {
this.address = new Address(this.addressForm.value);

this.companyService.addCompanyAddress(this.address);

this.activeModal.close();
```

}

How do I edit an object in the array properly?

Comment: Can you create stackblitz